# Redirection .htacess www to non-www http to https

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with redirection in .htacess file.
I`m using non-www and https

Example page: https://example.com/example is fine.

But, if type www  https://www.example.com/example than is a page redirected to https://example.com/index.php

Same result is with **http** http://www.example.com/example and http://example.com/example
result is always https://example.com/index.php

Is it possible to redirect all of this options to https://example.com/example

I didnt find any solution here.

**Thank you**

My .htacess

```html
   
## No directory listings
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>

## Suppress mime type detection in browsers for unknown types
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
</IfModule>

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Disable inline JavaScript when directly opening SVG files or embedding them with the object-tag
<FilesMatch "\.svg$">
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header always set Content-Security-Policy "script-src 'none'"
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site then comment out the operations listed
# below by adding a # to the beginning of the line.
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` on Joomla!
#
# Block any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root home page
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment the following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.

# Canonical HTTPS/non-WWW
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.rs [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don’t see any HTTP to HTTPS redirect in what you have shown.

Comment: I didnt paste code. Sorry. Here it is now.

Comment: This should not be placed at the very end, but before the internal rewrites are happening. Heck, it even has a comment there saying, `If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can achieve all of that by editing htaccess file, but I recommend you to check your configuration.php file in root and leave an empty value for live_site. Many times I had to solve different behaviour on my page when user was on the www and not-www url. Leaving the livesite value empty solved my problems.